# how to use array_push for json_encode

Tags: php, json, array-push

I am iOS developer and I am making Webservices in PHP for getting JSON Response.

Code which I wrote is:

```
    $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM wp_marketcatagories");
    $data =array();
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
                 {
                 $data[] = array_push($data, array('id' => $row['id']));
                 }
    $json = json_encode($data);
    echo $json;
```

This is what I want in result:

```
[{"id":"1"},{"id":"2"},{"id":"3"},{"id":"4"},{"id":"5"},{"id":"6"},{"id":"7"},{"id":"8"},{"id":"9"},{"id":"10"},{"id":"11"},{"id":"12"}]
```

But above code is giving me like this:

```
[{"id":"1"},1,{"id":"2"},3,{"id":"3"},5,{"id":"4"},7,{"id":"5"},9,{"id":"6"},11,{"id":"7"},13,{"id":"8"},15,{"id":"9"},17,{"id":"10"},19,{"id":"11"},21,{"id":"12"},23]
```

From where this 1, 3, 5 ,....  are coming ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

no need to assign it to `$data[]`. You are already pushing the values to the array `$data`

Just simply  use

```
 array_push($data, array('id' => $row['id']));
```

instead of

```
 $data[] = array_push($data, array('id' => $row['id']));
```

Answer (score 2):

> Array_Push(): Returns the new number of elements in the array.

...this is were your numbers are coming from and you're adding them to the array with your `$data[] =` statement

```
array_push($data, array('id' => $row['id']));
```

or

```
$data[] = array('id' => $row['id']);
```

Same result in this scenario

Answer (score 1):

You don't require to assign $data twice as you have written like this:
$data[] = array_push($data, array('id' => $row['id']));

array_push — Push one or more elements onto the end of array
syntax : `array_push(array,value1,value2...)`

Just write

```
array_push($data, array('id' => $row['id']));
```

or

```
$data[] = array('id' => $row['id']);
```